# Is it dangerous to have a javascript coding style enforcing no semicolon

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I recently started learning / using Vue.js for my personal project. However, their default ESlint rule enforces a rule that requires each statement end without semicolon. I later learned that airbnb's javascript style enforces semicolon and they explained a reason for it: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

It'd require some work. But if needed, I can switch to the airbnb style.

My question is, how bad is it to continue with Vue.js's default ESlint rule? If it's really bad, shouldn't Vue.js change their default ESlint rule to enforce having semicolons?

Answer (score 6):

This one's a divisive topic, almost as much as tabs vs. spaces. If you like semicolons, use them. If you don't, leave them. Regardless of what you do, [educate yourself on how ASI works](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons), use a linter, and write clean, readable code that does what it looks like it does. ASI can hit you whether you use semis or not.

Comment: Got it. Saved the article. Will take a look. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score -2):

Actually you can turn Eslint false in the file: ./config/index.js

```
// Use Eslint Loader?
// If true, your code will be linted during bundling and
// linting errors and warnings will be shown in the console.
useEslint: false,
```

Comment: Not linting your code at all just because you disagree with its semicolon policy seems a tad excessive...

Comment: Yeah, I do not want to turn off eslint. Just wasn't confident about  continuing the project with Vue.js's default rule of not allowing semicolons.